# How to plot bounding box given 4 vertices of a rectangle in python?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on OCR application and the annotations given for a image have 4 vertices of a traingle like this,

```
x1_1, y1_1,x2_1,y2_1,x3_1,y3_1,x4_1,y4_1, text_line
```

How can I plot this?

I tried to use `plt.rectangle` but it's only take xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax and here I have 4 vertices?

Comment: What's so hard in finding the min/max values for x and y?

Comment: @KlausD. is this how you find these values?-- (x1-x3), (y1-y3), (x2-x4), (y2-y4)

Answer (score 2):

if you insist on not finding the Min/Max value you could do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d=[1,1,1,4,3,4,3,1]
Xs = d[::2]
Ys = d[1::2]
for i in range(4):
    if i < 3:
        plt.plot([Xs[i],Xs[i+1]],[Ys[i],Ys[i+1]],'k-',lw=2)
    elif i == 3:
        plt.plot([Xs[i],Xs[0]],[Ys[i],Ys[0]],'k-',lw=2)

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

The right approach is to find the the left most point first, and then find the width and height and pass all 3 to the `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`.
In the case that you get the points sorted properly you just need to take `(x_1,y_1)` and then `width=x_4-x_1`, `height=y_2-y_1`

Simple example is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as pac

plt.axes()
rectangle = pac.Rectangle((1,1), 50, 20, fc='blue',ec="red")
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Which generate:

[image]

Comment: I tried to use patches.rectangle but it's not showing on my image. Can you please help me out.

Comment: I used `rect = Rectangle((x1, y1), width=x4-x1, height=y2-y1, linewidth=1,edgecolor='r')` then `ax,add_patch(rect)` but it's not plotting anything

Comment: @user_12 I don't know what is your problem, but you can see the edit and it works fine